# Some static images are not found on CDN when visiting My Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, images, cdn

Some images are not present when I visit [My Profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv) on careers.

```
GET http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/Img/arrow-gray-right-sm.png?v=8343ddbf8343 404 (Not Found)

GET http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/Img/bitbucket-icon.png?v=8343ddbf8343 404 (Not Found)

GET http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/Img/arrow-gray-down-sm.png?v=8343ddbf8343 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: The link you gave is not for your profile, it's for the logged in user profile, if exists. Anyway reproduced, there are only two for me though. (guess because I don't have bitbucket)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thats correct. the name of the page is "My Profile" :-)

Comment: I also have no bitbucket, but the icon is missing in the Open Source section

Comment: I believe this is fixed now as I can no longer reproduce it, but let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: @Alex while you're there, can you please take a quick look into [this client side error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Lmc.png)? I couldn't see any effect it has on the page, hence didn't start a bug report. (it's just annoying to see errors in the console. :))

Comment: @AlexWarren Seems to be fixed now. Thx